# shell scripting : when to test on the last command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I've this little bash script which imports a mongo database, do some change on it by running a java program and finally exports the modified database :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

credentials="-u xx -p yy"

#import database
ssh user@$viaDbHost <<EOF
  scp user@$prodDumpHost:$prodDumpPath $viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir
  mongorestore --drop --host localhost --db whitedb $credentials --gzip --archive=$viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir/db.gz
  rm $viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir/db.gz
EOF

#run a java program
javacp=/appli/java/lib/*
java -cp "$javacp" xx.yy.zz.MyApplication

#export database
ssh user@$viaDbHost "mongodump --host localhost --db darkDb $credentials --gzip --archive=$darkdumpPath"
```

I want to stop my script when an error has accurred and show a message, so I changed my shell to this version :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

credentials="-u xx -p yy"

#import database
ssh user@$viaDbHost <<EOF
  scp user@$prodDumpHost:$prodDumpPath $viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir

  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "@@@@@ ------- xxxxx"
    exit 1
  fi


  mongorestore --drop --host localhost --db whitedb $credentials --gzip --archive=$viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir/db.gz

  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "@@@@@ ------- yyyy"
    exit 1
  fi

  rm $viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir/db.gz

  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "@@@@@ ------- zzzz"
    exit 1
  fi
EOF

#run a java program
javacp=/appli/java/lib/*
java -cp "$javacp" xx.yy.zz.MyApplication

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  echo "@@@@@ ------- blablabla"
  exit 1
fi

#export database
ssh nf2@$viaDbHost "mongodump --host localhost --db darkDb $credentials --gzip --archive=$darkdumpPath"

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  echo "@@@@@ ------- blablabla 2"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

I feel that my script has changed to be ugly and has more lines because of these tests !

Is there a way to enhance this writing ?
Or a way to detect just the lines to be tested ?

Comment: you can write a function *my_exit() { echo "@@@@@ ------- $@"; exit 1 }* and then run *scp ... || my_exit xxxxx*

Comment: With any command, you can do `cmd || die "some message"`  Just implment the die function.  It is often sufficient to do `die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }`

Comment: You can even do `try() { "$@" || die "FAILED: $*"; }` and then just do `try cmd`

Comment: yes its more elegant this way. Does it work with `<<EOF` part ? @WilliamPursell

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to make sure you define the function on the remote side.  You won't be able to use the local function definition

Comment: on the remote ! how ? @WilliamPursell

Comment: You would need to put a definition inside the heredoc that is evaluated on the remote.  But see my answer below.

Comment: BTW, the reason it's not working is that `$?` is getting expanded on the local computer before being sent to `ssh` and hence to the remote computer. Specifically, it expands to the exit status of the last command the local shell ran, which was `credentials=...`, which succeeded so it's `0`. Therefore, what the remote shell sees is something like `if [ 0 != 0 ]; then ...`. You could escape the `$` character (e.g. `if [ \$? != 0 ]; then`) to prevent local expansion, but really the `||` options are cleaner.

Comment: thank you for you explanation :) @GordonDavisson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure error messages go to stderr.  You could try:

```
!/bin/bash

credentials='-u xx -p yy'

die() { printf "%s${1:+\n}" "$*"; exit 1; } >&2
try() { "$@" || die "FAILED: $*"; }

#import database
ssh user@$viaDbHost <<EOF || exit
  scp user@$prodDumpHost:$prodDumpPath $viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir || { echo error >&2; exit 1; }

  mongorestore --drop --host localhost --db whitedb $credentials --gzip --archive=$viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir/db.gz || { echo error >&2; exit 1; }

  rm $viaDbWhitedumpTmpDir/db.gz || exit 1; # rm emits its own error message

EOF

#run a java program
javacp=/appli/java/lib/*
try java -cp "$javacp" xx.yy.zz.MyApplication

#export database
try ssh nf2@$viaDbHost "mongodump --host localhost --db darkDb $credentials --gzip --archive=$darkdumpPath"

exit 0
```

But honestly for this script you probably don't even need to bother emitting any error messages.  Just do `cmd || exit 1` everywhere, and let each command emit its own error.

Comment: ok let me try it, but what means `"%s${1:+\n}" "$*"` ? sorry i'm really new to shell

Comment: It's a hack to allow blank lines.  It's not important.  The first string evaluates to either "%s" or "%s\n", depending on if the first argument is set.  That is, if "$1" is non-empty, then the format string is "%s\n", but if $1 is the null-string, the the format string is just "%s".  The "$*" just expands to the space separated concatenation of all the arguments to the function.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is great

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more or less generically, without having to check each command individually. Enable the `-e` option (which causes `bash` to exit when a command fails) and use an `EXIT` trap to give some details:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

at_exit()
{
    local code=$?
    local cmd=$BASH_COMMAND

    if test $code -ne 0; then
      echo "Command <$cmd> failed with status $code!" >&2
    fi

    exit $code
}

trap at_exit EXIT

# ... your script here ...
```

You can put those in a common file (e.g. `exit-trap.sh`) and `source` it into multiple scripts.

If you **don't** want the whole script to exit when a command fails, you can just add `|| :` at the end:

```
# don't exit if this fails
dont_care_if_it_fails || :
```

Comment: It seems too simple, Let me try it

Comment: both solutions are great and work well, I don't know which one I accept as the right answer :) Thanks again